# Alexa not returning SessionEndedRequest when user speaks nothing on echo show

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am using my skill for dot and show both. However, when user speaks nothing after repromt, dot is returning SessionEndedRequest, which I handled but speaking nothing. In echo spot, it is returning nothing, hence kept the session open. And I send the skill for certification and they failed it by saying that session kept open. If you send the request type SessionEndedRequest then my code handled that but when spot is not returning that, how one suppose to handle the SessionEndedRequest request.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I am using php, And it is not possible to show you code which is not happening... I mean no request is returning when user speaks nothing

Comment: What was your exact certification review comment?

Comment: It was saying that session kept open... later i added like asking something from user after every conversation and then they passed my certification. strange behavior from amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified this. The dot comes back with an EXCEEDED_MAX_REPROMPTS as expected, the spot stays quiet. Same code on the back-end.

This is an Alexa spot issue. Is anybody listening from Amazon?

Please file a bug report with them!